# Changing a postgres containers server port in Docker Compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy a second database container on a remote server using Docker compose. This postgresql server runs on port 5433 as opposed to 5432 as used by the first postgresql container.

When I set up the application I get this error output:

```
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1  |    Is the server running on host "db" (172.17.0.2) and accepting
web_1  |    TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

and my docker compose file is:

```yaml
db:
  image: postgres:latest
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: route_admin
    POSTGRES_USER: route_admin
  expose:
    - "5433"
  ports:
    - "5433"
  volumes:
    - ./backups:/home/backups
   
web:
  build: .
  command:  bash -c "sleep 5 && python -u application/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8081"
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "81:8081"
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
```

I feel the issue must be the `postgresql.conf` file on the server instance having set the port to 5432 causing the error when my app tries to connect to it. Is there a simple way of changing the port using a command in the compose file as opposed to messing around with volumes to replace the file?

I am using the official postgresql container for this job.

Comment: Are you saying postgres is running on 5432 in the container, but you want expose it on 5433?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Assuming postgres is running on port 5432 in the container and you want to expose it on the host on 5433, this ports strophe:

```
ports:
    - "5433:5432"
```

will expose the server on port 5433 on the host. You can get rid of your existing expose strophe in this scenario.

If you only want to expose the service to other services declared in the compose file (and NOT localhost), just use the expose strophe and point it to the already internally exposed port 5432.

Comment: No need to update the project `settings.py` Database settings either

Comment: Note, the syntax used to specify the ports is not valid; a white space needs to be placed between "-" and "5433:5432". Without this correction docker-compose fails to parse the yaml file and throws an error like "ERROR: The Compose file './xxxxxxxx.yaml' is invalid because: services.xxxx.ports contain  an invalid type, it should be an array"

Answer (score 174):

Some people may wish to actually change the port Postgres is running on, rather than remapping the exposed port to the host using the port directive. 
To do so, use `command: -p 5433`

In the example used for the question:

```
db:
  image: postgres:latest
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: route_admin
    POSTGRES_USER: route_admin
  expose:
    - "5433" # Publishes 5433 to other containers but NOT to host machine
  ports:
    - "5433:5433"
  volumes:
    - ./backups:/home/backups
  command: -p 5433
```

Note that only the host will respect the port directive. Other containers will not.

Comment: How can we add the command `-p 5433` to a Dockerfile, not a docker-compose file? I've been looking for an answer to this for a while but I keep getting lost.

Comment: @OsamaHafez: Just add `CMD ["-p", "5433"]` . Reference docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd . Setting the command this way relies on the entrypoint being a command prefix that expects the -p switch as the `postgres:latest` image from Docker Hub does.

Comment: Thanks - this worked for us! Per [command-line documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-postgres.html), the `PGPORT` environment variable works also.

Answer (score 22):

As was mentioned, this also works:

```
environment:
  - PGPORT: 5433
```

Comment: best answer from far

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it relies on environment variables similar to POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD