# Django database connection error to docker postgres image

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose

`settings.py` file:

```
from decouple import config

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': config('POSTGRES_DB'),                      
        'USER': config('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': config('POSTGRES_PORT'),
    }
}
```

`.env` file:

```
# DJANGO
SECRET_KEY='foobar'
DEBUG=False
ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1
# DATABASE
POSTGRES_DB=cheflist
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123123
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5433

DB_HOST=0.0.0.0
```

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - 5433:5433
```

The **first** question is that when I up the `postgres` image, everything goes well, BUT a message comes out in the logs:

```
db  | 2022-09-20 10:23:05.118 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db  | 2022-09-20 10:23:05.119 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db  | 2022-09-20 10:23:05.123 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db  | 2022-09-20 10:23:05.142 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-09-20 10:19:44 UTC
db  | 2022-09-20 10:23:05.163 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

For some reason, the port to which postgres is connected in docker is `5432`, although I specified `5433`.

The **second** question. When I run the `python manage.py runserver` terminal throws an error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "0.0.0.0", port 5433 failed: Cannot assign requested address (0x00002741/10049)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

... and it seems to me that this has something to do with my first question, since initially the image is not connected to the right port

Comment: You have to use 5432 port

Answer (score 1):

`postgresql` would start on port `5432` by default. So in it's container, `postgres` service is up in `5432`.

If You want to connect to it's container with another port, you should map that to `5432`. So:

```
ports:
      - 5433:5432
```

Now you can connect with port `5433` in host.

But for connecting via containers, you should connect to `5432`. So fix port to `5432` in settings and your second questions would be solved.

---

But if You want to change `postgres` port in it's container, you can use `command: -p 5433`:

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    expose:
      - "5433"
    ports:
      - 5433:5433
    command: -p 5433
```

See [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775702/changing-a-postgres-containers-server-port-in-docker-compose) for more details.