# Docker Django Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Tags: python, django, linux, docker, ubuntu

I'm running `Django` app on `Docker` container, the problem is it can't see the database connection is already up.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update

# Avoid tzdata infinite waiting bug
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Africa/Cairo

RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils vim curl apache2 apache2-utils
RUN apt-get -y install python3 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
RUN apt -y install certbot python3-certbot-apache
RUN ln /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN apt -y install software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository universe
RUN apt update
RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install django ptvsd
RUN apt install wait-for-it
RUN a2enmod headers
RUN service apache2 restart
COPY www/demo_app/water_maps/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD ./demo_site.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
EXPOSE 80 5432
WORKDIR /var/www/html/demo_app
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```yaml
version: "2"

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always 
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5332:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=(db name here)
      - POSTGRES_USER=(db user here)
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=(db password here)
  django-apache2:
    build: .
    container_name: test_water_maps
    
    restart: always 
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=(db name here)
      - POSTGRES_USER=(db user here)
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=(db password here)
    ports:
      - 5000:80
      - 5001:443
    volumes:
      - ./www/:/var/www/html
      - ./www/demo_app/kml_files:/var/www/html/demo_app/kml_files
      - ./www/demo_app/temp_kml_file:/var/www/html/demo_app/temp_kml_file
      - ./www/demo_app/upload:/var/www/html/demo_app/upload
    command: sh -c 'wait-for-it db:5432 -- python manage.py migrate && apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND'
    # command: sh -c 'wait-for-it db:5432 -- python manage.py migrate && python manage.py loaddata last.json && apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND'

    depends_on:
      - db
```

**Settings.py**

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5332,
    }
}
```

**THE ERROR**

when I run `docker compose up --build`

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "db" (172.24.0.2), port 5332 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Comment: what's the error

Comment: @ManojTolagekar edited the question showing the full error

Comment: You have the wrong `'PORT'` number, it needs to be the standard PostgreSQL port 5432.  Connections between containers ignore `ports:`.

Comment: [Changing a postgres containers server port in Docker Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775702/changing-a-postgres-containers-server-port-in-docker-compose) is a similar configuration issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app port for database should be default port on 5432